# draw line chart using hichart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have following data. (I get it using API)

```
   [{{2016 11 11 17 25 GET} 1} {{2016 11 12 17 10 POST} 1} {{2016 11 11 16 50 POST} 1} {{2016 11 11 17 15 POST} 1} {{2016 11 11 17 15 GET} 19} {{2018 4 18 16 5 GET} 1} {{2016 11 11 16 50 GET} 12} {{2016 11 11 17 10 GET} 36} {{2016 11 11 17 25 POST} 1} {{2016 11 11 17 10 POST} 11}]
```

in here {year month day hour interval method} count}. I want to draw line chart
x-axis - date time

y-axis - count 
according to method type, I want 2 lines in one graph. I'm new to stackoverflow.please help me.
I implement following code. But it's not working.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
type: 'spline'
},
title: {
text: 'Method Vs Time'
},
subtitle: {
text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
},
xAxis: {
categories: {Date.UTC(2018, 4, 18, 16, 5),
Date.UTC(2018, 4, 18, 16, 10),
Date.UTC(2018, 4, 18, 16, 15),
Date.UTC(2018, 4, 18, 16, 20),
Date.UTC(2018, 4, 18, 16, 25)},
tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
title: {
enabled: false
}
},
yAxis: {
title: {
text: 'Number of work orders'
},
labels: {
formatter: function () {
return this.value;
}
}
},
tooltip: {
split: true,
valueSuffix: ''
},
plotOptions: {
area: {
stacking: 'normal',
lineColor: '#666666',
lineWidth: 1,
marker: {
lineWidth: 1,
lineColor: '#666666'
}
}
},
series: [{
name: 'GET',
data: {1,1,20,13,47}
}, {
name: 'POST',
data: {10,4,2,13,4}
}]
});
```

Comment: In your static example, change from `data: {1,1,20,13,47}` to `data: [1,1,20,13,47]` and it should work.

Comment: it didn't work actually.

Comment: Ohh, you need to do it for your categories as well. See working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/f00h3pvb/2/

Comment: I suggest you do this instead though: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/f00h3pvb/3/

Comment: it is working and thank you so much